How can I connect aws instance running ssh on other port using aws ec2 connect
I need to connect aws instance using aws ec2 connect, but it is using port other than 22. While connecting to it, I'm getting access denied. Also is there any other way to recover pem?
I am getting error while connecting by default ec2 connect config.

I presume you are referring to EC2 Instance Connect? It has two parts -- one part pushes a temporary keypair to the instance and the second part establishes an SSH connection. You could use the first part to setup the authentication and then use your own SSH client to connect to the instance on a special port, using the temporary credentials created by the first part. See: Connect using your own key and SSH client
